# Em cascading issue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have one issue which is spinning my head right now. I got along with em's more or less well so far but here i ran into a nasty one.

I made a simplified markup example. I have the `<a>` inside the `<h2>`

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/KwgKKp)**

**HTML**

```
<h2>
    <a>This is title</h2>
<h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2{
    font-size: 2em;
}

a{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Now I want to put `<a>` tag inside the `<h2>` but it will too big because em units are relative to their parent. Is there way to fix it? Thank everyone.

Comment: You know about `rem`, right?

Comment: check this out: http://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/

Comment: @torazaburo It only support IE9+ and does it better for responsive mate?

Comment: If you can't use rem, for whatever reason, you could just write a rule for this specific case `h2 a { font-size: .75em; }`. The downside would be that you would need to change this value if you ever changed your `h2` or `a` font-size (and could be extra work in the future)

Comment: Oops, forgot about IE8, which has 3% global market share. Don't understand your comment about "responsive".

Comment: @torazaburo I mean does it good scaling for responsive screen :)

Comment: @Marcelo Or you can add class to `<h2>` as: `h2.whatever` and then the descendant a would be the correct size.

Comment: I'm not seeing an responsivity issues here. `rem` refers to the font size of the body tag. It doesn't care about the device or its size. If you're worried about responsiveness, then add a media query for `a { font-size... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the font is too big, set it smaller. Seriously. When you set font size to `1.5em`, it *means* that you set it to 1.5 times the parent element’s font size. If you  don’t want that, set it to some other value. If you want it to be 1.5 times the basic font size and the parent element’s font size is twice the basic font size, simply calculate 1.5/2, i.e. set `font-size: 0.75em`.

There is no reason to change to units that work less reliably or less flexibly. Simply use `em` according to its definition.

Then again, it is seldom a good idea to have links inside headings *or* to change font size inside a heading. But technically it can be done, and it usually takes just one division operation.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with Torazaburo. `rem` sets size relative to the root element, rather than the parent element so if you define a size for your `html`element, rem elements will derive their size from that (you don't need to define a size for the html element, you could just let the users browser determine it.)

There is good article about rem on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've chosen to use `em`s, and that's how they work. You make your bed, and you lie in it.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `rem`, if you can do without IE8 support.

Otherwise, it's back to `px`. And what's the problem with that? If you're using a CSS pre-processor, you can make that value a variable, making it easy to change or make dependent on something else.

Comment: I'll read about REM but now I can fix my issue by adding class to `<h2>` :D

Comment: `h2 a { font-size: 1em; }` would do it I think, but note that taking this approach will get really, really nasty quite quick

Comment: @ckuijjer It would be better if you add class to `<h2>` :D

Answer (score 0):

or you can try inherit to the nearest parent.

**HTML**

```
<h2>
  <a>This is title</h2>
<h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2{
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 a{
    font-size: inherit;
}
```